Accessing attribute parameters in a DiagnosticAnalyzer
Let's suppose I have attributes like this
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyAttribute: Attribute
{
     public MyAttribute(string name) {}
     public MyAttribute(int number) {}
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
[My("whatever")]
[My(333)]
class XAttribute: Attribute {
}

[XAttribute]
public class Usage {}

Note that XAttribute has multiple MyAttribute instances attached.
How can I get the "whatever" and the 333 in the analyzer?
This is how I try to get the MyAttribute instances:
private static void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var node = context.Node;

    var attributes = node
        .DescendantNodes()
        .OfType<AttributeSyntax>()            
        ;

    foreach (var attribute in attributes)
    {
        // Get the symbol for the attribute
        var attributeSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(attribute).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
        if (attributeSymbol == null) continue;

        var myAttributeInstances = attributeSymbol
            .ContainingType
            .GetAttributes()
            .Where(a => a.AttributeClass?.Name == nameof(MyAttribute))
            .ToList();

        if (myAttributeInstances.Count == 0) continue;
        
        /// HERE
    }
}

I get to HERE, and I have the proper number of AttributeData instances in the list. But I can't get hold of the constructor parameters passed to them. ConstructorArguments properties are empty. I have the same issue with the values passed for the attribute properties as named constructor arguments NamedArguments property is likewise always empty.
Note: the attributes are defined in a different assembly than the one being analyzed.

Using ConstructorArguments works as expected. You should check if the code you are analyzing is the code defined at the beginning of the question.

Obviously this is a sample. I can't post the oroginal code here. But the scenario is this: I need the cosnstructor parameters of the attributes on the attribute used in the analyzed code.

foreach (var argument in attributeInstance.ConstructorArguments)
{
    if (argument.Kind == TypedConstantKind.Primitive)
    {
        // "whatever" and 333 will be here
        var value = argument.Value;
        // Do something with the value
    }
}


This is what I was expecting. But as I mentioned: the ConstructorArguments properties are empty. For all intances.

Where are you getting your SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext from?

public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration, SyntaxKind.PropertyDeclaration, SyntaxKind.AssemblyKeyword);
}
It is in a DiagnosticAnalyzer
